# Localhost error connection refused

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, gruntjs

I installed a [yeoman generator from here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-mvc6-angular) to setup a new project with ASP.NET MVC6 and AngularJS and Grunt, but when I run it like shown in the description, I got an error:

> Connection refused in the browser.

I didn't add any own content until now and just want to see the default generated view on localhost.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I also followed the tutorial and didn't succeed so far. The only configuration I’ve managed to build the project was with dependencies set to `-beta4` (I do have other vresions installed). But with beta4 I get the runtime exception _System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment'_ has been registered…But this leads to completely new research :)
However starting a new ASP.NET 5 project from VS and adding angular with `yo` works like a charm. Perhaps you can start this way in order to start hacking and adopt the project structure later.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So you think I should just create a new project by myself and adopt the sctructure?

Comment: Yes, in case your goal is to start coding that might be the fastest, since generator seems a bit problematic. If you want a structure like  mvc6-angular would create (with Server and Client folders), just do that structure manually. It would be nice to report a problem to maintainers though. Happy coding!